# Wie groß ist der Wirkungsbereich der Präpositionen auf den Kasus der dahinter stehenden Nomen?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Wir betrachten die folgenden Sätze:

> Ich muss ab *nächster Woche* wieder arbeiten.
>
> Ich muss ab *nächster Woche Montag* wieder arbeiten.
>
> Ich muss ab *nächster Woche Montag dem 1.7.* wieder arbeiten.

Ändern die Präpositionen den Kasus aller dahinter stehenden Nomen oder nur das direkt dahinter stehende Nomen?

Comment: Solange die zusätzlichen Information nur ein Satzeil sind (also nur mehr informationen über den Startzeitpunkt hinzugefügt werden), ja.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: D.h., der Satz `Ich muss ab Montag nächster Woche, dem 01.07., wieder arbeiten` wäre korrekt? Für mich sagt "ab" dass danach ein Zeitpunkt und danach dann was in diesem Zeitraum passiert - arbeiten gehen ohne dass es ein Ende (im Satz) hat. Ansonsten würde ich sagen: im täglichen Sprachgebrauch mache ich dann wohl den Fehler. Kann es auch ein Pleonasmus wie weißer Schimmel sein?

Comment: Der 1.7. ist ein Mittwoch. Die 7 benötigt auch einen Punkt. (Der erste siebte, nicht der erste sieben). Wenn man nicht in ein Formular mit Kästchen für das Datum schreibt, dann ergänzt man auch keine führenden Nullen üblicherweise, außer vielleicht es drohen Dukementfälschungen, also dass jmd. das Datum in den 11., 21. oder 31.7. ändert - einen Monat 17 gibt es jedoch nicht, so dass an der Monatsposition nur bei den Ziffern 1, 2 eine Fälschung droht. Dies hier klingt jedoch nicht nach einem formalen Dokument.

Comment: @userunknown Der Satz ist ein fiktives Beispiel. Deswegen habe ich nicht versucht , dass der Tag mit dem Datum übereinstimmt. Außerdem da das Jahr nicht genannt  ist, kann man bestimmt einen 1.7. finden, der auf einen Montag fällt. Z.B. 1.7.2019

Comment: Das habe ich mir schon gedacht bzw. wusste ich vorher schon, nichtsdestotrotz wollte ich es thematisieren, da ich wg. der führenden Nullen schon dabei war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das hängt nicht von der *Stellung* ab, sondern von der *Beziehung* der Nomen untereinander.

Wenn z.B. ein Nomen eine possessive Beziehung ausdrückt, steht es im Genitiv, d.h. der Skopus der Rektion endet dort:

> Ich reise vor dem Ende *des Monats* ab.

Wenn die Nomen dagegen die Funktion von Appositionen ausüben, zieht sich der regierte Kasus durch die gesamte Phrase, egal wie viele Nomen es sind:

> Der Feiertag ehrt Abraham Lincoln, *den Befreier* der Sklaven, *den Helden* des Bürgerkrieges.

(Man beachte, wie der Kasus vom Akkusativ zum Genitiv und wieder zurück wechselt, weil auch die Funktion von Apposition zum Possessiv und wieder zurück wechselt.)